# javascript on click does not work

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#HyperLink12").click(function () {
            $('#webpage_datalist_product_full').animate({ left: "+=285" }, 400);
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink12" runat="server" 
                                ImageUrl="slide_arrow_right_click.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>

                        </div>
```

on click the javascript does nothing ,i added my html code

Comment: can you post the piece of html?

Comment: Did you load jquery before the <script> block above?

Comment: @TonyZampogna yes at the start of the code,

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to achieve when clicking the hyperlink is the animation you show above, I recommend preventing the default action usually executed by clicking hyperlinks, which is navigating to the URL value stored in its `href` attribute. So, for a start, change your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#HyperLink12").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); //Prevents the default hyperlink click action
            $('#webpage_datalist_product_full').animate({ left: "+=285" }, 400);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If this doesn't work and you need more help, feel free to comment; I will update my answer.